# Oracle - Edit a pipeline before it returns from a function

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

#### Context

I was not able to find the correct terminology. So I'll give a brief explanation of what it is.
I sold some products and i don't know how my client will pay, so my ERP create a registry of a Receivable.
However, my client had already made 2 other orders, so now i have 3 Receivable registry. however, the client doesn't pay and they renegotiate the debt.
That can happen N times like the following chart.
What I want to do is.
Pass the Receivable 'D' ID then it finds the original Receivable (A0,A1,A2) and from that get all Receivable movement.

#### Current Function

First, i use a Recursive Function that brings me the origin.
Then a recursive function that already brings all the payments when the origin is a single Receivable.
However, when the origin has more than one Receivable, it will duplicate the values. Since (A0,A1,A2) are aggregated.

#### Current scenario

[image]

#### QUESTION

While using Pipelined function before returning, is it possible to pass through the data and "update/delete" it?
Or i'll have to make another function only to validate the data?
What would be the best mode to treat it?

#### EXPECTED RETURN

| POSITION | Father Node | STATE | New Node | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A0 | RENEGOTIATED | B | 100 |
| 0 | A1 | RENEGOTIATED | B | 100 |
| 0 | A2 | RENEGOTIATED | B | 100 |
| 1 | B | CASH | CASH | 100 |
| 2 | B | RENEGOTIATED | C | 200 |
| 2 | C | RENEGOTIATED | C0 | 50 |
| 2 | C | RENEGOTIATED | C1 | 50 |
| 2 | C | RENEGOTIATED | C2 | 50 |
| 2 | C | RENEGOTIATED | C3 | 50 |
| 3 | C2 | RENEGOTIATED | D | 50 |
| 3 | C3 | RENEGOTIATED | D | 50 |
| 3 | C0 | OPEN | NULL | 50 |
| 3 | C1 | OPEN | NULL | 50 |
| 4 | D | OPEN | NULL | 100 |

## Real Scenario

### Current output

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and your recursive query.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if you can create a function that will do updates and inserts before returning the data? I think that's possible, but not a good idea. Validate your data on insert, not select. That may even return an error if you try to do something like `select * from table(mypipelinedfunction)`. Selects shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: by "UPDATE/DELETE"  i mean  before the RETURN scan the Table Object and validate if theres any duplicate values.
"DELETE" `LOOP IF ... THEN PIPE ROW(i).delete; ELSE EXIT END LOOP` 
"UPDATE" `LOOP IF ... THEN PIPE ROW(i).delete; PIPE ROW(NEW ROW); ELSE EXIT END LOOP` i was not able to find anything like this in the documentation. or i'm just looking at the worng place